# Symmetrical function analysis

Tags: functions

Another question made me think about this function and what it means:

If we say we have some function $f(x),x\in[0,1]$ which is symmetrical about $x=1/2$, then that means:
$$f(u)=f(1-u),u\in[0,1/2]\tag{1}$$
If we assume that $f$ is continuous and differentiable then define another function:
$$g(x)=\frac{f(x)+f(1-x)}{2}\tag{2}$$
now because of how we have defined $f$ I believe we can say:
$$g(x)=f(x)\tag{3}$$
But by looking at the definition of $g$ and differentiating we get:
$$g(x)=\frac{f'(x)-f'(1-x)}{2}\tag{4}$$
Now following on from $1$ it appears to me that:
$$f'(u)=f'(1-u)\tag{5}$$
Since the two functions are equal, however differenting would give:
$$f'(u)=-f'(1-u)\tag{6}$$
and combining these would give:
$$f'(u)=f'(1-u)=0\tag{7}$$
and hence:
$$g'(x)=0\tag{8}$$
But something seems wrong to me here, could anyone explain?

Comment: How did you get equation (5)?

Comment: Ah yes I see where I have gone wrong now, In my head it made sense but when I draw it, it does not work

Comment: Now I just get that $g'(x)=f'(x)$